# Approach to show up some part of the webpage in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dom, webbrowser-control

I am just wondering if there is any approach to catch only some part of the web page using WPF and show up it?

Any ideas?

*Thank you!*

Comment: Like go into the HTML and only take a part of the HTML out and stick it in the browser control?

Comment: @Hexxagonal Yeah... Do you have any stupid sample how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reference SHDocVw.dll.  From there, it is a matter of casting `WebBrowser.Document` to `MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2` and using IntelliSense to figure out how to access the DOM and remove what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my solution.**

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)MainBrowser.Document;

if (null != doc)
{
     foreach (IHTMLElement element in doc.all)
     {
           if (element.id == "wrapper")
           {
                 HTMLDivElement container = element as HTMLDivElement;

                 dynamic dd = container;

                 string result = dd.IHTMLElement_innerHTML;

                 // You get ANY member of HTMLDivElementClass

                  break;
             }
     }
}
```

[image]